# How can I dynamically increase font size with Javascript and why is my current function not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I'm trying to increase the font size of my page using a javascript function but it's not working. Is there a syntax problem with my code or is it not possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Javascript:

```
function changeFontSize(fontvar) {
var div = document.getElementById("webchat_history");
var currentFont = div.style.fontSize.value;

div.style.fontSize = currentFont + fontvar+ "px";
}
```

HTML:
    `<span onClick="changeFontSize(10);" style="font-size:16px;">Aa</span>`

I want to increase it by x amount (fontvar) rather than specifying a specific font size because my font sizes are set in an external stylesheet. When/if I need to modify the stylesheets, I'd rather not have to update the Javascript too.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: I think this line `div.style.fontSize = currentFont + fontvar+ "px";` is operating with strings, so you will get `"16" + "10" + px"` resulting in `"1610px"` instead of `"26" + "px"`!

Comment: I'm getting "Object Required" in the javascript console

Comment: @Ivozor, if that was the case, shouldn't I be seeing really LARGE font then? Or is 1610px too large for the browser to handle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This script should work:

```
function changeFontSize(fontvar) {
    var div = document.getElementById("webchat_history");
    var currentFont = div.style.fontSize.replace("px", "");

    div.style.fontSize = parseInt(currentFont) + parseInt(fontvar) + "px";
}
```

Comment: No change. I'm getting "Object Required" in the Javascript Console on IE8 still

Comment: check my answer again, I have made some changes

Comment: I appreciate all your help, but I think I found my problem. "webchat_history" is a class, not an Id. So this problem actually had nothing to do with the function.

Comment: yes, but the solution depends on how many divs you have with same class, do you have one or many?

Comment: if it's only one you can use: `var div = document.getElementsByClassName("webchat_history")[0];`

Answer (score 1):

I found this amazing script:
https://github.com/simplefocus/FlowType.JS

Demo:
http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

After additional debugging, I realized the "id" I was using, `webchat_history`, was not actually an ID. It was the *class* for ID `history`. I'm going to create additional classes and use `document.getElementById('history').className = "webchat_history_medium";` to change font sizes.